# what is the find command which will Create a file called look, which will look for and show, in the current directory and its sub-folders:

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Create a file look, which will look for and show, in the current directory and its sub-folders:

- everything that starts with an `a` or,
- all the files ending with a `z` or,
- all files starting with `z` and ending with `a!`.

My attempt:

```bash
find . -type f -name "a*" -o -name "*z" -o "z*a!"
```

Comment: please show us your attempt to solve the problem. Are you trying to solve this is bash or in python?

Comment: What's your question?  And why are you only showing regular files (`-type f`) in the first alternative, if that's not what the requirement asks for?

Comment: Why is this tagged for Python?

Comment: You missed a `-name`

Comment: @Elerium115 i am using bash

Comment: You can also probably use the `-regex` switch

Comment: @Braudo could you remove the python tag then? thanks

Comment: i am getting this error; find: invalid expression; I was expecting to find a ')' somewhere but did not see one.

Comment: You didn't read my first comment then

Comment: @Braudo your question is still tagged python

Answer (score 0):

Boolean logic precedence is at work here:

```bash
find . -type f \( -name 'a*' -o -name '*z' -o -name 'z*a!' \)
```

Also, you were missing a predicate `-name` before the last glob string.

`-o` in this case is the logical OR operator.

`find` also accepts `-a` for a logical AND operator. If you don't specify one, it's implied, i.e. `-type f -name foo` REALLY is `-type f -a -name foo`.

Since OR has lower precedence than AND, you must group them using parentheses.

Since Bash and other shells reserve `(` as a keyword, you must escape them when inserting the literal character on the command line. `\(` is equivalent to `'('` which is equivalent to `"("` for our purposes. I just wrote `\(` because it's shorter. `"\("` is also a literal `(` but the slash is unnecessary. Here's an equivalent version of the command above, where every shell "word" is quoted. It's quite a bit noisier, and it's just to show you what's going on:

```bash
'find' '.' '-type' 'f' '(' '-name' 'a*' '-o' '-name' '*z' '-o' '-name' 'z*a!' ')'
```